# missiles skip in collision detection

Tags: c++, collision-detection, marmalade

I'm trying to work on spaceinvader. I have problem that missiles or the bullets skip frames due to its fast speed. I tried to use the previous position of the bullet in the collision check, but still, the collision does not work. it's pretty working on bullets with slow speed. Kindly see the attached video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOVc-HGNI9Q&feature=youtu.be

```
  void Bullet::Update(float dt)
{
    Position.y -= 0.50 * dt;

    Vel = (Position - prevPosition).GetNormalised();

    if (Position.y < 0)
    {
        IsDestroyed = true;
    }
    else
        IsDestroyed = false;

    prevPosition = Position;

}
```

and for collision check:

```
// if there is intersection
        if (IntersectsWith((*it)->BoundingRect, barrierRect))
        {

            // subtract (*it) bullet position from barrrier's rect 
            int normX = (*it)->prevPosition.x + (*it)->Vel.x - barrierRect.x;
            int normY = (*it)->prevPosition.y + (*it)->Vel.y - barrierRect.y;

            // barrier image pixels 
            uint32* ptr = (uint32*)pixels;
            // height of the barrier

            int pixelOffset = normY*51 + normX;
            unsigned int color = ptr[pixelOffset];
            // look up the color if its not black, it should be green
            if (color != 0xFF000000)
            {
                // delete the bullet
                Bullet *bullet = *it;
                it = ship->Bullets->erase(it);
                delete bullet;
                ship->Canfire = true;
                isCollision = true;

                // blast a circle around that bullet hit position
                int radius = 9;
                for (int y = -radius; y <= radius; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = -radius; x <= radius; x++)
                    {
                        if (x*x + y*y <= radius*radius)
                        {
                            int j = x + normX;
                            int i = y + normY;
                            int pixelOffset = i*51  + j;
                            ptr[pixelOffset] = 0xff000000;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues like this often come from the fact that the bullet gets through the target; frame A it's before and frame B it's passed it, and neither in frame A nor frame B you had a bounding box intersection.

A way to solve this is: in frame B, you extend your bullet's bounding box from the position it was in in frame A. This would encompass 'all the infinite positions the bullet have been in' during the 'frame transition'.

**Edit**:

As per request, here is a pseudocode sample. Note that it is assumed that everything is axis-aligned, that the origin is bottom left, and that bullets are going from 0 to infinite in the y-axis.

```
// Stuff to add to your main update
update() 
  // When you update your bullet posisiton
  bullet.previousPosition = bullet.position 
  bullet.position  = blaBlaBlaUpdatePosition()
  bullet.mositionBoundingBox = 
    makeMotionBoundingBox( 
      bullet.previousPosition,
      bullet.position,
      bullet.size )


// Take into considration the traveled distance between this frame and the 
// previous frame
makeMotionBoundingBox( positionLast, positionNow, itemSize )
  rect = new rectangleBoundingBox
  rect.position = positionLast
  rect.size.x = itemSize.x
  rect.size.y = positionNow.y - positionLast.y + itemSize.y


isInMotionCollision( bullet, target )

  if ( bullet.mositionBoundingBox.intersect( target.boundingBox )
    return true;

  return false
```

Comment: can you elaborate that in pseudo code ? or picture ? I didn't get it

Comment: what's rect.size.y ? you mean rect height ?

Comment: Yes, if a vector is used to represent a size, the width is going to be kept in the x, and the height is going to be kept in y.

Comment: I adapted your code, but still I don't get accurate collision all the time :S

Comment: so basically you try to adjust the bounding box height to work from FrameA when the bullet is in FrameB so that it collides

Comment: It's more like a 'ray casting' from the position in frame A to the position in frame B. You could try to intersect your target with a line segment from positionLast to positionNow. I don't know if marmalade has this kind of feature, though..

Comment: is the calculation of the bullet impact correct ? because the bullet sometimes hit the some parts of the barrier that are away from the hit point

Comment: You'll forgive me, it's hard to see the big picture here...

Comment: I mean is that code correct ?  // subtract (*it) bullet position from barrrier's rect 
            int normX = (*it)->prevPosition.x  - barrierRect.x;
            int normY = (*it)->prevPosition.y  - barrierRect.y;

Comment: and why not only adjusting the bounding box position to be the prevposition and not adjusting the size ? does adjusting the size matter ?

Comment: It looks as if your code just creates a hitbox that encompasses both the `last` and `now` iterations of the object. Which is a huge mistake, because if the object is moving diagonally, the hitbox increases disproportionately in size the faster the object moves, resulting in many erroneous collisions. I had a similar idea involving...well, they say pictures are worth a thousand words, so I drew [this](https://imgur.com/8N9oH2J). In each illustration, the black boxes on each end represent one "cycle" (frame) of the game.

Comment: @BradenBest I suggest you write an answer with this :)